# Barometer Operation in case of Recursive Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have to find instruction count of Merge Sort using Method called Barometer Operation.

**What is Barometer Operation?**

- A “barometer instruction”  is selected
- Count = number of times that    barometer instruction is executed.
- Search algorithms:  barometer    instruction (x ==    L[j]?).
- Sort algorithms:  barometer instruction    (L[i] <= L[j]?).

For e.g:-

```
     for(int i=0;i < n;i++)
       A[i] = i + 1
```

**Barometer operation = +** in body of loop

**count(+) = n**

So now problem with Merge Sort is that it is recursive algorithm and I do not know how to choose one particular instruction so that I can count number times that particular instruction is executed.

Comment: Well if your given the type of function that is going to be called, wouldn't you take the O(n) of MergeSort (n * logBASE2(n)) and multiple the number of instances of the barometer specified operator. Or does your method have to include any recursive type?

Comment: Make sense. I think... I know now to proceed. Barometer operator would be "<" where actual comparison is made. And this operator is called (n/2) times recursively by two methods which divides list and then main merge operation happens exactly (n-1) times.So after solving summation equation it gives (nlog(n)+c) Thanks @SGM1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@aphex** and **@SGM1** for showing me the right direction. I guess the solution to problem is as follows:

I have use the same code as **aphex** used. But only problem with solution is that **aphex** forget to maintain it for worst case. So according to me barometer operation/instruction must be

`first(left) <= first(right)`

Because this is where actual comparison is going on. Barometer operator would be "<=" where actual comparison is made. And this operator is called (n/2) times recursively by two methods which divides list and then main merge operation happens exactly (n-1) times.So after solving summation equation it gives (nlog(n)+c)

Code from Wiki with little modification by **aphex**

```
function merge_sort(list m, var count)
    if(length(m))>0
        count++;

// if list size is 0 (empty) or 1, consider it sorted and return it
// (using less than or equal prevents infinite recursion for a zero length m)
if length(m) <= 1
    return m

// else list size is > 1, so split the list into two sublists
var list left, right
var integer middle = length(m) / 2
for each x in m before middle
     add x to left
for each x in m after or equal middle
     add x to right
// recursively call merge_sort() to further split each sublist
// until sublist size is 1
left = merge_sort(left,count)
right = merge_sort(right,count)
// merge the sublists returned from prior calls to merge_sort()
// and return the resulting merged sublist
return merge(left, right)

function merge(left, right)
var list result
while length(left) > 0 or length(right) > 0
    if length(left) > 0 and length(right) > 0
        if first(left) <= first(right) // My Barometer Operation
            append first(left) to result
            left = rest(left)
        else
            append first(right) to result
            right = rest(right)
    else if length(left) > 0
        append first(left) to result
        left = rest(left)
    else if length(right) > 0
        append first(right) to result
        right = rest(right)
end while
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the code from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). You need to count on the split part. The splits are made in `merge_sort(list m)`.. You need to add the counter as input parameter(`var count`) see below. The counter must be `count=0`. Every time the method get called and the list `lenght>0`, then you increase the counter by 1.

```
function merge_sort(list m, var count)
      // Count here
    if(length(m))>0
            count++;

    // if list size is 0 (empty) or 1, consider it sorted and return it
    // (using less than or equal prevents infinite recursion for a zero length m)
    if length(m) <= 1
        return m

    // else list size is > 1, so split the list into two sublists
    var list left, right
    var integer middle = length(m) / 2
    for each x in m before middle
         add x to left
    for each x in m after or equal middle
         add x to right
    // recursively call merge_sort() to further split each sublist
    // until sublist size is 1
    left = merge_sort(left,count)
    right = merge_sort(right,count)
    // merge the sublists returned from prior calls to merge_sort()
    // and return the resulting merged sublist
    return merge(left, right)

function merge(left, right)
    var list result
    while length(left) > 0 or length(right) > 0
        if length(left) > 0 and length(right) > 0
            if first(left) <= first(right)
                append first(left) to result
                left = rest(left)
            else
                append first(right) to result
                right = rest(right)
        else if length(left) > 0
            append first(left) to result
            left = rest(left)
        else if length(right) > 0
            append first(right) to result
            right = rest(right)
    end while
    return result
```

For the wikipedia example you need to call the pseudo code like this `merge_sort([38,27,43,3,9,82,10], 0)`.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Can you explain me more specifically what I didn't understood? You are looking for a barometer operation and this operation is merge_sort from the example. I also altered the wikipedia example to implement it. Not sure what's wrong by voting a -1 on my answer.

Comment: Where is your barometer operation? Basically barometer operator or instruction must be an array comparison. for e,g:- (a[i] < a[j]) now this is barometer instruction/operation. Now we have to count how many times this instruction gets executed. But according to your logic you are counting number of calls to a function and not to a particular instruction.

Comment: what about counting length(m) <= 1 ?

Comment: Ahh.. no ... I guess it should be this line 
' first(left) <= first(right) ' in merge function. because this line is making the actual comparison. Make sense?

Comment: yes, it makes sense. But this get called, only if there are more than one elements in the list. if length(m) <= 1 must be also considered.

Comment: See Barometer operations are for Worst Cases mostly.

Comment: okay. Then I suggest you to post your own answer and accept it as an answer. Nice to learn something new.